# How do I add JSON object as new level to another JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have a code that gets in the end collection of two JSON objects, something like this.

```
var jsonL1 = {"holder1": {}}
var jsonL2 = {"section":"0 6","date":"11/12/13"}
```

I would like to insert jsonL2 inside jsonL1.holder1 and merge it to one JSON object.

Desired output

```
{
    "holder1": {
        "section": "0 6",
        "date": "11/12/13"
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: That is not JSON. Those are javascript object literals.

Comment: @patrick dw as long as you don't add objects other than strings, arrays, numbers, hashes and nulls, aren't they interchangeable?

Comment: @Radek S: No. JSON is a data exchange format that happens to be a subset of JavaScript object literal notation. JSON is language independent. This might not be the best analogy, but consider XML: XML can also be used as data exchange format. Often it is transformed into DOM. So DOM can be used to represent an XML document. Same for JSON and objects in JavaScript. The only difference is that JSON can be "naturally" converted to JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Felix is right. JSON data is a string of characters that follow the JSON specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as easy as:

```
L1.holder1 = L2
```

I removed the "json" from the variable names, as @patrick already said, you are dealing not with "JSON objects" but with object literals.

See also: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

You also might want to learn more about [objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 4):

If you want the first object to *reference* the second, do this:

```
jsonL1.holder1 = jsonL2;
```

If you wanted a *copy* of the second in the first, that's different.

So it depends on what you mean by *merge* it into one object. Using the code above, changes to `jsonL2` will be visible in `jsonL1.holder`, because they're really just both referencing the same object.

---

A little off topic, but to give a more visual description of the difference between JSON data and javascript object:

```
    // this is a javascript object
var obj = {"section":"0 6","date":"11/12/13"};

    // this is valid JSON data
var jsn = '{"section":"0 6","date":"11/12/13"}';
```